# Row requiring data in first field

Tags: python, rows

Running into a problem where row[3] is requiring data in the csv for the first line or it throws an error.

This field is for description/comments so its optional.

Also any advise on what has to be ugly code for the quotes or anything else would be great. Hacked this together from various sites.

Thanks for the time and info.

```
print "#######  CSV FORMAT REQUIREMENTS ##########" '\n',
print "     File should be in the same directory as this script" '\n',
print "     First column needs to be device or network name" '\n',
print "     Second column needs to be IP address" '\n',
print "     Third column should be mask in CIDR starting with a slash (/32)" '\n',
print "     Forth column for any comments, can be blank" '\n',
print "     See IPSample.csv file for example format" '\n',
print "name of csv file? (In same directory as this script)",
infile = raw_input()
print "" '\n',
print "####### Your Output file" '\n',
print "Output file can be any name, should end it with .txt" '\n',
print "name of output text file? (Will be saved in same directory as this script)",
outfile = raw_input()

import csv

f = open(infile, 'r')
e = "edit "
s = "set subnet "
com = "set comment "
qq = '"'
dash ='-'
n = "next"
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
import sys
sys.stdout=open(outfile,"w")
print "##### Double Check output for errors" '\n',
print "##### Its best to copy/paste this in small batches in case of any errors" '\n',
print "##### Comments with empty quotes will be ignored for FortiGate" '\n',
print "configure firewall address" '\n',
for row in csv_f:  #for always end in a colon
    print e + str(row[0]+dash+row[1]+row[2])                #creates object name
    print s + str(row[1]+row[2])            #Creates object host or subnet
    print com + qq + str(row[3])+qq     #Creates comment
    print n                             #inserts 'next' command

f.close()
```

Comment: What does the csv that you're reading look like? Does it always have 4 columns?

Comment: Yes 4 columns First 3 are required but the 4th is optional.
Thanks

Comment: You might need to do something to only print the 4th column if it exists. Could you paste the output of each `row`? Just do `print(row)` for all rows in the csvs and paste and example row with 3 columns and one with 4.

Comment: Here's the output from the`print(row)`

`['vendor1', '192.168.1.2', '/32', 'vendor web server']`<br/>
['dcenter', '192.168.10.0', '/24', '']`<br/>
['dcenter', '172.16.10.22', '/28', 'internal web server']`

vendor1 192.168.1.2 /32 vendor web server
dcenter 192.168.10.0 /24 
dcenter 172.16.10.22 /28 internal web server

Comment: Hmm, what is the specific error that you're getting? You could just only execute `print comp + qq + str(row[3]) + qq` if `len(row) == 4`.

Comment: This is the CSV example. 4th column has description so it works
vendor1 192.168.1.2 /32 vendor web server
dcenter 192.168.10.0 /24 
dcenter 172.16.10.22 /28 internal web server

Comment: Sorry can't figure out how to paste in the info in the correct format.

Comment: It's ok. I would edit your answer using the [markdown guide](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). It's easier to see code and what not in answers and not comments :).

Comment: Here's the error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/project/address-creator-v6.py", line 36, in <module>
    print com + qq + str(row[3])+qq  #Creates comment
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: where would I add the `len(row) == 4`

Comment: I gave it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for the length of the row if you know that each row will always have at least 3 columns. Your for loop would then look like:

```
for row in csv_f:
    print e + str(row[0]+dash+row[1]+row[2])                #creates object name
    print s + str(row[1]+row[2])            #Creates object host or subnet
    if len(row) == 4:
        print com + qq + str(row[3])+qq     #Creates comment
    print n                             #inserts 'next' command
```

Comment: What does the '4' represent in this  == 4?

Comment: It's a boolean to check the length of the row. The `4` itself is an `int` and the whole boolean check is `len(row) == 4`.